# Get Last Modified Date for a script Deployment in NetSuite

Tags: scripting, netsuite

How do I get the last modified date of a deployment script? This can neither be searched with a saved Search nor it is available in the records browser. 
[image: This is a screenshot of it.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting it from a savedsearch by adding a column date/time.

Answer (score 0):

Create a saved search on script deployment and see for date when you add columns.
[image: Saved search]

You can load same search form script using var res = nlapiSearchRecord('scriptdeployment', 997, null, null);

or load record 
var rec_id = record.getId();
var tb =  nlapiLoadRecord('scriptdeployment', rec_id);

Comment: The formuladate column doesn't work. It returns a null. Though I need the modified date, not the created date. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: try getting it from the latest date in log where type = Edit